# Autostart program in Xfce

Tags: xfce, session, xubuntu

After installing Skype and the Jabber client Psi, I set both programs to start within Session and Startup, Application Autostart. The first time I boot the computer, the programs launch as expected. However, if I log out and then log in again, the programs do not start. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `Clear saved sessions` and disable `Automatically save session on logout`, close all applications and logout/login. Xfce4 trips over its own saved sessions from time to time in my experience.